# Can not see new version of Picasso library on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

When I go to android studio and add I only see  `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2`
`Project Structure -> Dependencies -> com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2.`

How can I add the latest version like 2.5.2?

`com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2` version looks buggy. Cant load any of the images on SD card.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your build.gradle file and add:

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` on the dependencies section.

Square's Picasso has the latest version and instructions in their [github page](https://github.com/square/picasso)

If you're using the GUI of the you can just select the library you wish to remove and click on the `-` sign on the bottom left corner (disabled in the picture)

[image]

Then you select the `+` to add a new library, choose `Library Dependency` and put the latest picasso version like so

[image]

Should be on the bottom of the list now... I suggest you rebuild your project afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line to your gradle file  dependancy tag and Sync the file

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

For more http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: you can also put picasso:2+ to make automatic update

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your build.gradle

```
dependencies{ compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File 
--> Project Structure 
--> select app under Module 
--> select Dependencies 
--> select + button 
--> Library Dependency 
--> type Picasso in search box 
--> Enter
```

there you can see the list of Picasso library files

```
--> select the latest one.
```